# Setting field visibility on a model, in controller, before getting data?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to filter down the fields I get returned within my controller, ideally before getting the results as not to have to loop around the collection after. The hidden fields aren't always the same, and might differ from what was initially set in the model.

This is my current (not working) code:

```
$model = new Model;
$model->setHidden($toHide);
$results = $model->where($filters)->get();
```

The above code always defaults back to what was initially set in the hidden variable instead of is currently set.

I know this code works:

```
$results = Model::where($filters)->get();

foreach($results as $i => $row){
    $row[$i] = $row->setHidden($toHide);
}
```

But ideally I don't want to loop the results to set the hidden on each model.. The idea being I can change the hidden fields based on other attributes (what the user can see, which controller route the user has taken, etc) from within the controller.

Comment: This doesn't answer how to hide dynamically, but another approach would be to use `Model::select(['column1', 'column2', ...])->where($filters)`, where you specify which columns you want...

Comment: @ljubadr Would be a good idea, however my data needs to join a different table, and writing a join in the controller feels wrong.

Comment: for joins you could use laravel [Query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#query-scopes)

Comment: Look at [local scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#local-scopes)

Comment: So you could write `public function scopeLeftJoinWithDifferentTable($query)` and use it like this `Model::LeftJoinWithDifferentTable()`

Comment: @ljubadr Interesting, I'll have a look into that tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Agree with @ljubadr, textbook case for a query scope.